# Is there is any control available in Cocoa application just like UITableView?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to implement UITableView like view in Cocoa application, How can I implement this? is there any controls available in Xcode 4?

Comment: thanks.now i am going to learn NSTavleview

Comment: I got this  video link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oj7CrJi7ylA

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following links might help you:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTableViewTutorial

[NSTableView Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154623/nstableview-tutorial)